# What does "du monde" here mean?

Tags: sens

> Peupeu semble obéir à son père, c’est-à-dire qu’il regagne l’intérieur
>   de la maison, mais pour bientôt en ressortir par la porte d’entrée. Il
>   se faufile dans la ruelle en étouffant ses pas. Il se dirige avec foi
>   vers la maison où scintille la lampe de Mademoiselle Perdrigaits. La
>   porte du rez-de-chaussée est entr’ouverte. Peupeu pénètre avec
>   précaution dans l’obscur corridor et glisse un œil rapide, à droite,
>   où il y a une autre porte entr’ouverte. Non loin d’un grand feu de
>   bois il y a des choses confuses, **du monde**, les trois Rois sages, les
>   bergers, l’âne, le bœuf, le Petit Jésus, son papa, sa maman (conclut
>   Peupeu). Mais ce qui est sûr, c’est qu’il y a là, au-dessous de
>   l’étage de Mademoiselle Perdrigaits, un joli poupon, qui est le fils
>   du charpentier Moinot, et que sa mère fait tetter.

This is from  "La Noël de mes enfants" by Francis Jammes.
https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_No%C3%ABl_de_mes_enfants

What does "du monde" here mean?
I can't understand the meaning.

I am glad if somebody kindly teach me.

Comment: As @Philippe writes, it's a synonym of *des gens*, except that *monde* is *un nom indénombrable* — a mass noun like *lait* "milk". So *du lait*, *du monde*, *beaucoup de lait*, *beaucoup de monde*. You can think of it as the same *monde* as in the phrase *tout le monde*. Also, it makes a good double entendre out of the title of the painting *L'origine du monde* (not safe for work)... But yes, please consult a dictionary first and then explain what you found if you're still not sure what something means.

Comment: Than you so much.

Comment: Please look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first. If you did so and found nothing satisfactory, mention that in your question.

Answer (score 5):

I would expect it to be in any good dictionary, but it's simply a synonym for "des personnes", or "des gens".

Comment: @HiroshiInagaki  Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation).

Answer (score 2):

It means, a bunch of people...